# Не учитывать одну из областей клика

Tags: jquery

Есть 2 области `body` и `.click`. При клике на `.click` я делаю объект `.view` видимым, а при клике на `body` я его скрываю.

Но тут возникает проблема пр  клике на `.click`  учитывается область `body` и получается два события объект открывается и сразу скрывается.

Вопрос: Как при клике на `.click` игнорировать клик на `body`?

```js
$('.click').click(function() {
  $('.view').show();
});
$('body').click(function() {
  $('.view').hide();
});
```

```css
a {
  background: red
}

span {
  background: green
}

body {
  background: black
}

.click {
  background: yellow
}

.view {
  display: none;
  background: white;
  color: red;
  padding: 10px
}

div {
  padding: 10px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div class="click">
    <a>link</a>
    <span>span</span>
  </div>
  <div class="view">
    Text
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Дело в том, что событие "всплывает" по всему дереву элементов. Чтобы это предотвратить, если необходимо, нужно вызвать stopPropagation метод у события. Более подробно об этом можно прочесть здесь: https://learn.javascript.ru/event-bubbling

```js
$('.click').click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  $('.view').show();
});
$('body').click(function() {
  $('.view').hide();
});
```

```css
a {
  background: red
}

span {
  background: green
}

body {
  background: black
}

.click {
  background: yellow
}

.view {
  display: none;
  background: white;
  color: red;
  padding: 10px
}

div {
  padding: 10px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div class="click">
    <a>link</a>
    <span>span</span>
  </div>
  <div class="view">
    Text
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Ну теперь другая проблема. Он не скрывается по клике на `body`